# Biztalk: How to pass filename within msgbody into stored procedure by WCF-Custom port

Tags: biztalk, biztalk-2010

I have BizTalk application with FILE incoming port and  WCFCustom sending port.

WCFCustom sending port is calling stored procedure and passing message body as xml parameter to this stored procedure by specifying Template property like on screenshot below.

Body of the message is specified by the **bts-msg-body** tag.

**Questions:**

1.Is there any way to pass **file name** into stored procedure as additional parameter ?

2.Is thre way to send multiple parameters into stored procedure ?

[image]

Comment: I take it you want it as a messaging only solution without using an BizTalk Orchestration to create a XML message that has the filename and file payload in it?  Because with an Orchestration and a XML message it is easy to do.  I've not been able to find any way of accessing context properties of the in the template which is what you would need to make it work as a messaging only without creating custom pipeline components.

Comment: yes, creating custom pipeline component is one way to do this , but I'm curious if it possible to do it without pipeline component.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer to 2, is it possible to send multiple parameters into the stored procedure.
Yes it is

```
<ns0:StoredProc xmlns:ns0="http://schemas.microsoft.com/Sql/2008/05/Procedures/dbo">
<ns0:document>
<bts-msg-body xmlns="http://www.microsoft.com/schemas/bts2007" encoding="base64"/>
</ns0:document>
<ns0:documentname>
Test
</ns0:documentname>
</ns0:StoredProc>
```

How to populate the documentname from the message context property, that is the bit I can't figure out. Maybe someone else can come up with a suggestion for that.

Answer (score 2):

1. Yes, with a promoted property.
2. Yes, as per Dijkgraaf's answer.

The way I would do this is:

- Use the "Consume Adapter Service" BizTalk Project Add-in to generate a schema for your stored procedure that can have elements for multiple parameters (examples [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd788445.aspx)) or create one by hand if you like.
- Edit the schema to specify the element to contain your file name is promoted as "http://schemas.microsoft.com/BizTalk/2003/file-properties#ReceivedFileName". This will cause the XML Assembler to copy this value from the message context into the field.
- Create a map to copy incoming message into message body element as CDATA. Add this map on your send port.
- Use the XMLTransmit pipeline to populate the file name field from the message context

If your file is not XML you will probably need a custom pipeline component instead of a standard map (I would use the FixMsg example from the SDK).

Comment: Hey Bert, the trick is that I do not want to map tags from message into stored procedure parameters, because I want transfer any xml file from FILE port into WCFCustom port.And stored procedure will detect type of file by xml root name and act accordingly.

Comment: I think I would try using the FixMsg component then. Put that at the start of the pipeline and set it to prepend something like `<StoredProc><Document><![CDATA[` and append `]]></Document><FileName/></StoredProc>` so that it matches the schema for the stored procedure. Then use XMLAssembler in the assemble stage and the file name will be added into the parameter.